# ValueError: Value must be one of {'doubleAccounting', 'double', 'singleAccounting', 'single'}

Tags: python, excel, load, openpyxl

After writing the following code I get the following error. Help would be appreciated in understanding why openpyxl which is designed to work with EXCEL cannot open a basic excel file. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(file_name, read_only= True)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-9ebd7e3bdd2c> in <module>()
      4 
      5 
----> 6 wb = load_workbook(file_name, read_only= True)

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, guess_types, keep_links)
    199         wb.loaded_theme = archive.read(ARC_THEME)
    200 
--> 201     apply_stylesheet(archive, wb) # bind styles to workbook
    202 
    203     # get worksheets

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in apply_stylesheet(archive, wb)
    171         return wb
    172     node = fromstring(src)
--> 173     stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
    174 
    175     wb._cell_styles = stylesheet.cell_styles

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in from_tree(cls, node)
     97         for k in attrs:
     98             del node.attrib[k]
---> 99         return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
    100 
    101 

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
     70             if hasattr(desc, 'from_tree'):
     71                 #descriptor manages conversion
---> 72                 obj = desc.from_tree(el)
     73             else:
     74                 if hasattr(desc.expected_type, "from_tree"):

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py in from_tree(self, node)
     84 
     85     def from_tree(self, node):
---> 86         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     84 
     85     def from_tree(self, node):
---> 86         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
     87                 attrib[tag] = obj
     88 
---> 89         return cls(**attrib)
     90 
     91 

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\fonts.py in __init__(self, name, sz, b, i, charset, u, strike, color, scheme, family, size, bold, italic, strikethrough, underline, vertAlign, outline, shadow, condense, extend)
     85         if underline is not None:
     86             u = underline
---> 87         self.u = u
     88         if strikethrough is not None:
     89             strike = strikethrough

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\nested.py in __set__(self, instance, value)
     34 
     35             value = self.from_tree(value)
---> 36         super(Nested, self).__set__(instance, value)
     37 
     38 

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py in __set__(self, instance, value)
    143         if value == 'none':
    144             value = None
--> 145         super(NoneSet, self).__set__(instance, value)
    146 
    147 

C:\Users\Gaston\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py in __set__(self, instance, value)
    128     def __set__(self, instance, value):
    129         if value not in self.values:
--> 130             raise ValueError(self.__doc__)
    131         super(Set, self).__set__(instance, value)
    132 

ValueError: Value must be one of {'single', 'double', 'singleAccounting', 'doubleAccounting'}
```

I have tried taking out the `read_only` part etc. The error has to do with Excel styles. I am using Excel 2016 and the file type is xlxs.

Comment: Please paste the whole error as text with formatting. You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: The exception is self-explanatory: there is a problem with the styles in your source file.

Comment: That does not exactly help. How do you fix it? I am trying to open the file. The file is a file that openpyxl creates so if it can't open one of the files that it creates the package is not exactly on the useful side.

Comment: The problem is related to how openpyxl saves a file. When I copy the contents of sheet to another sheet in a different workbook and save as an excel workbook then the code above opens the file without any problems.

Comment: There is a problem with the source file's underlining styles. I have gone into every sheet CTRL-A CTRL-U CTRL-U and resaved. When I re-save it tells me that there is something wrong w/ the format. So I save once again under the same name after deleting the original file.

The reality is that I don't know what is going on. Whether the solution is the underline thing or resaving.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this temporarily by comment the two lines in
"python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py"" file
[image]

I just run the code in debug mode, so I can save the change forcedly.

Comment: This solution is to comment the code of installed/third party library, which is not a direct solution of above issue. Is python community has done some work on this issue? Please comment/give for some better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution : `Correct the excel file manually by clicking on the "enable editing" for the protected view and save the file`.

Post this try to read the file

```
df = pd.read_excel("file_name.xlsx")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a bug in an Excel processing library called RubyXL, which writes an invalid value to the .xslx file: https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL/issues/405

Excel tolerates the invalid underline style ement `<u val="1"/>` written by RubyXL, by interpreting it as a single-underline style, but `openpyxl` does not tolerate it.

Maybe your file has been corrupted by RubyXL or by another tool with a similar problem?

Comment: I've raised a bug on OpenPyXL as well, because I think it should be more tolerant here.  Excel is.

https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1766